# Load generated webpack chunks from runtime chunk

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm partially updating an existing web application with new (react) code and am using webpack to bundle everything together for production. Because the existing HTML page (in fact it is XML converted to HTML) is already there, I can't use the `index.html` that is generated by the `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

What I would like to achieve is that webpack generates a small `runtime.bundle.js` which will dynamically load the other generated chunks (`main.[contenthash]` and `vendor.[contenthash]`), instead of adding these entries as `script` tags to the `index.html`. This way the `runtime.bundle.js` can be set to `nocache` whereas the large other chunks can be cached by the browser and correctly fetched on code changes.

As an example, here is the body block of the generated `index.html`, note the comment:

```html
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- I want these two files below not injected as script tags, 
         but loaded from the runtime.bundle.js file above  -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors.31b8acd750477817012d.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.1e4a456d496cdd2e1771.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The runtime file is already loading a different chunk that is imported dynamically from JS with the following code:

```js
const App = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "modulex" */ './App'));
```

This creates the following snippet somewhere within the `runtime.bundle.js`

```js
          a = document.createElement('script');
        (a.charset = 'utf-8'),
          (a.timeout = 120),
          i.nc && a.setAttribute('nonce', i.nc),
          (a.src = (function(e) {
            return (
              i.p +
              '' +
              ({ 1: 'modulex' }[e] || e) +
              '.' +
              { 1: '0e0c4000d075e81c1e5b' }[e] +
              '.js'
            );
```

So can the same be achieved for the `vendors` and `main` chunk?

The only other alternative solution that I can think of is to use the `WebpackManifestPlugin` to generate the `manifest.json` and use this to inject the chunks into the already existing HTML file.

Comment: I am struggling with the exact same scenario. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @nevermind777 I wrote a script that creates a 'runtime' JS file which will inject the hashed chunks as scripts into the head of a HTML document (using the `manifest.json` create by the `WebpackManifestPlugin`. This script can be called as an npm script. I can share if you like...

Comment: Thanks @Sjiep sounds interesting, I would like to check out your solution

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem in the end by creating a script that uses the `manifest.json` (which is generated by the `WebpackManifestPlugin`) to generate a `runtime.js` script that will load the chunks dynamically on page load and insert this `runtime.js` into the head of an `index.html`. This callable from the `npm scripts` section using [tasksfile](https://github.com/pawelgalazka/tasksfile) npm package.

In you webpack configuration, add the plugin into the plugin array:

```
{
  // your other webpack config
  plugins: [
    new ManifestPlugin(),
    // other webpack plugins you need
  ],
}
```

The I have the following external JS file that I can call from my `npm scripts` using the tasksfile npm package, which is configured to call this function:

```
// The path where webpack saves the built files to (this includes manifest.json)
const buildPath = './build';
// The URL prefix where the file should be loaded
const urlPrefix = 'https://www.yourdomain.com';

function buildRuntime() {
  const manifest = require(`${buildPath}/manifest`);
  // Loop through each js file in manifest file and append as script element to the head
  // Execute within an IIFE such that we don't pollute global namespace
  let scriptsToLoad = Object.keys(manifest)
    .filter(key => key.endsWith('.js'))
    .reduce((js, key) => {
      return (
        js +
        `
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = urlPrefix + "/js/${manifest[key]}";
        document.head.appendChild(script);`
      );
    }, `(function(){var script;`);
  scriptsToLoad += '})()';

  // Write the result to a runtime file that can be included in the head of an index file
  const filePath = `${buildPath}/runtime.js`;
  fs.writeFile(filePath, scriptsToLoad, err => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Error writing runtime.js: ', err);
    }
    console.log(`\n${filePath} succesfully built\n`);
  });
}
```

The function basically loops over all JS entry files in the `manifest.json`.
Script tags are then created with these entries as `src` property and these script tags are then added to the `document.head` as children (triggering the loading of the entries). 
Finally this script is save to a `runtime.js` file and stored in the build directory.

You can now include this `runtime.js` file into you html file and if all paths are set correctly you chunks should be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

HtmlWebpackPlugin offers a [`chunks` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin#user-content-options) that you could use to selectively include certain entries from your webpack config's `entry` object. Using that, you could actually simplify most of the logic from your custom script by putting it into a separate `src/dynamic-load.js` file, only adding it to the plugin config:

```js
entry: {
    runtimeLoader: './src/dynamic-load.js'
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        // ...
        chunks: [ 'runtimeLoader' ]
    }),
]
```

(Another example of `chunks` usage can be seen [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/218#issuecomment-183066602)).

It's possible that even their built-in `templateParameters` would allow you to put the build output file names into a variable and read them in `dynamic-load.js`. You'll have to make your own template for it, but that could be one route. You can even see how their suggested [`templateParameters` example did it](https://github.com/waysact/webpack-subresource-integrity/blob/main/webpack-subresource-integrity/index.ts#L168).

If that doesn't work, you could always resort to getting the bundled output file names through webpack itself via the `afterEmit` hook and then output those into a JSON file that `dynamic-load.js` would call. The gist being something like below, but at that point, you're just doing the same thing `WebpackManifestPlugin` does.

```js
plugins: [
    {
        apply: compiler => {
            compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('DynamicRuntimeLoader', compilation => {
                const outputBundlePaths = Object.keys(compilation.assets)

                // output to dist/files.json
                saveToOutputDir('files.json', outputBundlePaths);
            });
        }
    },
    // ...
]

// dynamic-load.js

fetch('/files.json').then(res => res.json()).then(allFiles => {
    allFiles.forEach(file => {
        // document.createElement logic
    });
});
```

One final note: WebpackManifestPlugin is actually an [assets manifest](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6436) and doesn't produce a [correct manifest.json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json). They *should* update their [default file name](https://github.com/shellscape/webpack-manifest-plugin#filename) to `assets-manifest.json` but I guess no one has pointed this out to them yet.

Answer (score 0):

// https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11816#issuecomment-716402552

```
declare var __webpack_get_script_filename__: any;
const oldFn = __webpack_get_script_filename__;

__webpack_get_script_filename__ = (chunkId) => {
  const filename = oldFn(chunkId);
  return filename + `?v=${environment.timestamp}`;
};
```

Barry run... RUNNNNN... with this super power script!